# Android plugin pattern

Tags: android, plugin-pattern

I am going to implement plugin pattern in my Android application.

Right now I have created:

```
public abstract class PluginReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

In an external plugin there is for example

```
public class SmsPluginReceiver extends PluginReceiver
```

`PluginReceiver` class contains also a few methods like `getIcon`, `getName` and so on.

`SmsPluginReceiver` is registered in `AndroidManifest.xml` as a receiver with specified intent-filter action:

```
<receiver android:name=".plugin.sms.SmsPluginReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="hsz.project.plugin" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In main application I am searching for all available plugins with `PackageManager`:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent("hsz.project.plugin");
List<ResolveInfo> matches = manager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
```

and I got one `ResolveInfo` object.

I do not know at all what should I do with it - how to access `SmsPluginReceiver` data (icon, name, ...) ?

Comment: Not sure it's possible. You might need to send an ordered broadcast in order to retrieve this kind of information from each of the registered receivers - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.os.Handler,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29. Otherwise you might need to setup your own registry of receivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plug-in architecture in Android can be REAL tricky.  How tricky depends on what approach you need.  I had a project where they wanted to integrage plug-in fragments into the main apps Activity.  If you take that approach, the plug-ins will have to be signed with the same key as the main app.

If you can integrate plug-ins by simply launching activities, then I would recommend using PendingIntents.  Somehow, you have to get your plug-in to register the PendingIntents into plug-in slots to they can be activated.  I used package manager to identify new plug-ins, sent it an intent instructing it to register itself, then exposed a ContentProvider so it could register itself.  I then called the PendingIntent's it registered to integrate it into the app experience.

Is that the information you're looking for?